# Updating UI element without dispatching to the main queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, grand-central-dispatch

I have a `dispatch_block_t` which is passed to **another function**, and this **block** will be called when the **function** finishes the asynchronous task. But the problem is that I don't know **which thread** this block will be called.

I want to update my UI in the **main thread**, hence I want to use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{...})
```

to update my UI. But I am afraid that this will cause a **deadlock** if such occasion happens

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("my.label", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        // outer block is waiting for this inner block to complete,
        // inner block won't start before outer block finishes
        // => deadlock
    });

    // this will never be reached
});
```

Is there a way to prevent the **deadlock**? Like updating the UI element without using the `dispatch queue`. Is it possible to create a `weak reference` to `self` in order to update the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your example with NSLogs and you'll notice that deadlock doesn't occur. This is due to the fact that using `dispatch_async` just submits a block to the queue without waiting for it to finish execution (in contrary to `dispatch_sync`).

So running this code:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("my.label", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSLog(@"1");
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"2");
    });
    NSLog(@"3");
});
```

Will produce the following log:

```
Testtt[32153:2250572] 1
Testtt[32153:2250572] 3
Testtt[32153:2250572] 2
```

Moreover, I'm concerned that using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{...})` here is commonly-used technique which ensures that the consumer gets the result on the main thread (i.e. consumer doesn't 'care' about threading).

Why, though, you use `dispatch_block_t` to pass a completion block? In my opinion, it's a bit confusing to use something like that on the consumer side - I would pass an anonymous (without typedef) block or create my own typedef for these simple completion blocks.

Comment: Thanks! But actually the deadlock is pointed by my customer and he just says I should use weak reference to self in order to prevent possible deadlock. What kind of occasion can dispatch_asyn leads to deadlock? I am not sure if he is right...

Comment: I'm not sure if using strong reference to self in a block can lead to a deadlock (personally, I can't imagine such a situation). It may, however, cause a reference cycle but that a completely different story. It would be easier to address the issue if you posted the code where the deadlock occurs.